# GCC with c++17 standard cannot compile range-based for case with different begin/end data type

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

For C++17, it has a small change with proposal [p0184r0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0184r0.html)，which make it possible to specify different begin() and end() type for a user-defined type, to compatible with range-based for. But it seems gcc will failure on following cases:

```cpp
#include<iterator>

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class read_t
{
    public:
        using data_type = int;
        read_t()
        {
        }


        ~read_t()
        {
        }

        struct end_marker {};
        class iterator
        {
            public:
                using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
                using value_type = data_type;
                using difference_type = long int;

                iterator(read_t& reader)
                    : m_reader(reader)
                {}
                data_type operator*()
                {
                    return m_i;
                }
                iterator& operator++()
                {
                    return *this;
                }
                bool operator!=(end_marker&)
                {
                    m_i ++;
                    return m_i <= 3;
                }
            private:
                read_t& m_reader;
                int m_i = 0;
        };

        iterator begin() { return iterator(*this); }
        end_marker end() { return end_marker{}; }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    for (auto i : read_t())
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

with error message as:

```
~/test >>> g++ -std=c++17 -o b0 b.cpp
b.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
b.cpp:56:26: error: inconsistent begin/end types in range-based ‘for’ statement: ‘read_t::iterator’ and ‘read_t::end_marker’
   56 |     for (auto i : read_t())
      |                          ^
~/test >>>
```

My gcc compiler is gcc 10.2.0, on Manjaro platform. The same code is passed with clang 11.0.1 and vs 2019.

Comment: Changing the `!=` overload's signature to  `bool operator!=(const end_marker&)` made it compile for me under gcc 10.2 (this is the first thing that jumped into my eyes). Not sure what the *real* answer here is, this requires some digging into the standard.

Comment: it seems changing the signature to `bool operator!=(end_marker)` would also make it pass. The end() return a rvalue, and the original `bool operator!=(end_marker&)` cannot bind the input parameter to the rvalue. What confuse me is the error information GCC complains.

Comment: I don't see what the issue is, with respect to the standard. Given how range iteration is specified in C++17 I do not see any reason why the `!=` overload is the problem here (even though it is slightly non-kosher, in its non-working form). I think this is a legitimate gcc bug (with a workaround).

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug. Could you report it to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ ?

Comment: Is it normal that your `operator !=` mutates the iterator (whereas `operator++` doesn't)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a compiler bug as far as I can tell. If you replace the range-for loop with its non-range equivalent, as per the standard, it compiles:

```
 {
                                       // init-statement
    auto &&range = read_t() ;          // auto &&range = for-range-initializer ;
    auto begin   = std::begin(range) ; // auto begin   = begin-expr ;
    auto end     = std::end(range) ;   // auto end     = end-expr ;
    for ( ; begin != end; ++begin ) {
        auto i = * begin ;             // for-range-declaration = *__begin ;
        cout << i << endl;             // statement
    }
}
```

---

A workaround seems to be to declare the argument of `operator!=` to be a reference to const. Which should have been done in the first place since the referred object isn't modified. Alternatively, use a value argument - this would theoretically be more efficient.